# Does Array.map reuse instance of React component?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have met weird symptom while I use Array.map to render multiple items in React.
In the code below, filtered1 and filtered2 should show same result. However, The result is different.

It seems that Array.map reuse the instance of React component.
Is this right behaviour of Array.map?

You can see the full source and demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/silverlining/3nauec4d/).

```
class Row extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            id: props.data.Id,
            isTrue: props.data.IsTrue
        }
    }
    render () {
        const {data} = this.props
            return (
            <tr>
                <td>{data.Id}</td>
                <td>{data.IsTrue ? 'true' : 'false'}</td>
                <td style={{backgroundColor:(this.state.isTrue ? 'green' : 'red')}}>{this.state.id}</td>
                <td style={{backgroundColor:(this.props.data.IsTrue ? 'green' : 'red')}}>{this.props.data.Id}</td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
}
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { filter: 'all' }
    }
    render () {
        const data = [
            {"Id":"1","IsTrue":true},{"Id":"2","IsTrue":true},{"Id":"3","IsTrue":false},{"Id":"4","IsTrue":false},{"Id":"5","IsTrue":true},
            {"Id":"6","IsTrue":true},{"Id":"7","IsTrue":false},{"Id":"8","IsTrue":true},{"Id":"9","IsTrue":true},{"Id":"10","IsTrue":false}]

        const filtered1 = 
            data
            .filter(x => this.state.filter == 'all' || x.IsTrue)
            .map((item, index) => (<Row key={index} data={item} />))

        const filtered2 = 
            data
            .map((item, index) => (<Row key={index} data={item} />))
            .filter(x => this.state.filter == 'all' || x.props.data.IsTrue)

        return (
            <div>
                <select value={this.state.filter} onChange={e => this.setState({filter: e.target.value})}>
                    <option value='all'>All</option>
                    <option value='ts'>Trues</option>
                </select>
                <div>
                  <span>
                    <h1>filter -> map</h1>
                    <table>
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Id</th>
                          <th>IsTrue</th>
                          <th>State Value</th>
                          <th>Props Value</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        {filtered1}
                      </tbody>
                    </table>                  
                  </span>
                  <span>
                    <h1>map -> filter</h1>
                    <table>
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Id</th>
                          <th>IsTrue</th>
                          <th>State Value</th>
                          <th>Props Value</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        {filtered2}
                      </tbody>
                    </table>                  
                  </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: probably same `key` issue. Try adding something unique to them. E.g `key={'filter1' + index}` and `key={'filter2' + index}` to their corresponding parts

Comment: When you `filter` first, the elements to the right of elements which get removed are shifted to the left, which means their indexes change.

Comment: unfortunately, key is not the issue. because you can see the same problem if you remove the filtered2 part of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the index of the array as the key; use some unique information about the `item`, ex:

```
key={`${item.Id}:${item.IsTrue}`}
```

By using the index of the array, React thinks the items are the same even though they are different. React doesn't look inside the item, it only looks at the key value. If the keys are the same, it reuses the "old" component without re-rendering it.

For further reading, here are the docs for [Lists and Keys](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html). You'll notice they **don't** use the index as the key except in one scenario, where they clearly warn that:

> Only do this if items have no stable IDs

Comment: amazing, v important concept